# Ajustar archivo csv en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Tengo una lista de datos de MySql y la convertí en una lista de python. Creé una función para exportar el archivo a Excel mediante `csv`. El problema es que, si bien la función separa cada "row" de la lista, no separa las columnas y las escribe pegadas. ¿Qué tengo que modificar?, gracias.

```
conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root", password="El_Passw", database="La_BD")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
query2="SELECT * from ticket"
        
cursor1.execute(query2)
            
result=cursor1.fetchall()
            
lista_tickets=[]
for r in result:
    lista_tickets.append(r)
print(lista_tickets)            
conn.commit()
conn.close()
#---------------------------------------

def exportar_a_csv():
    fln=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), \
    title="Lista de Tickets", filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), \
    ("All Files", "*.*")))
    with open(fln, mode="w") as myfile:
        exp_writer=csv.writer(myfile, delimiter=",")
        for i in lista_tickets:
            exp_writer.writerow(i)
```

EDIT: hice los cambios sugeridos en la respuesta, la función funciona, pero el archivo creado sale en blanco. Adjunto una foto de cómo salía la primera vez.

Nuevo código:

```
def exportar_a_csv():
    #Base de datos
    conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor()
    cursor1.execute("SELECT * FROM ticket")
    registro= cursor1.fetchall()
    
    
    lista_tickets=[]
    for r in registro:
        lista_tickets.append(r)
    print(lista_tickets)            
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
    fln=tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), \
    title="Lista de Tickets", filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), \
    ("All Files", "*.*")))
    with open(fln, mode="w") as myfile:
        df = pd.DataFrame( myfile)
        df.to_csv( "archivoQuery" , sep="," )
```

Foto: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A eso me refería con que no separa las columnas.

Comment: No entiendo a que te refieres con "no separa las columnas y las escribe pegadas". Podrías agregar una muestra (no es necesario que sean datos reales) en forma de texto de como queda el csv por favor? Eso dirá mucho más que una descripción.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que quede para cualquiera que tenga este mismo problema, ésta fué la solución que encontré y que me funcionó:

```
def exportar_a_excell():
    #Base de datos
    conn= conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",user="root",password="Baelca1", database="Lista_datos_Baelca")
    cursor1=conn.cursor(dictionary=True)
    query='SELECT * FROM ticket'
    cursor1.execute(query)

    #Marco de datos pandas
    df_sql_data= pd.DataFrame(cursor1.fetchall())
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    file = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension=".xlsx")
    df_sql_data.to_excel(str(file)+'.xlsx', index=False)
```

Convierte la tabla de mysql (con todo y columnas) en un archivo excell.

Answer (score 0):

facilitate la vida con el metodo to_csv de pandas

```
import pandas as pd

conn=mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost",
        user="root", password="El_Passw", database="La_BD")
cursor1=conn.cursor()
query2="SELECT * from ticket"
        
cursor1.execute(query2)
            
result=cursor1.fetchall()
            
lista_tickets=[]
for r in result:
    lista_tickets.append(r)
print(lista_tickets)            
conn.commit()
conn.close()
#---------------------------------------

def exportar_a_csv():
    fln=filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir=os.getcwd(), \
    title="Lista de Tickets", filetypes=(("CSV File", "*.csv"), \
    ("All Files", "*.*")))
    with open(fln, mode="w") as myfile:
        df = pd.DataFrame( myfile)
        df.to_csv( "archivoQuery" , sep="," )
```

Debido a que no uestras el contenido de myfile, solo esto te puedo indicar

Comment: Hola, @DanteS. Pido disculpas por el silencio, he tenido muchos problemas con la pc. Hice los cambios sugeridos en la respuesta, pero el archivo ahora se escribe en blanco, no hay nada en el excell.